# UseWaitCursor doesn't work in an async Task

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, mouseevent

My current project requires a lot of forms. A lot of logic is the same so I want to create a `BaseForm` from which all Forms inherit.
I encounter a problem with `UseWaitCursor` and `Cursor.Curent = Cursors.WaitCursor`, it doesn't work if I load the data async (in a new Task).

This is the `BaseForm`:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form ' Normaly in BaseForm.Designer.vb put I put it here for symplicity

    Protected Sub BeginLoadingData()
        Application.UseWaitCursor = True
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Application.DoEvents()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub EndLoadingData()
        Application.UseWaitCursor = False
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
    End Sub

End Class
```

And I use it like this:

```
Public Class MainForm
    Inherits BaseForm ' Normaly in Mainform.Designer.vb put I put it here for symplicity

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        LoadData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadData()
        BeginLoadingData() ' Working as long as I doesn't move the mouse

        Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                  ' ... Long running task

                                  Me.Invoke(Sub() EndLoadingData())
                              End Sub)
    End Sub

End Class
```

If I run the loading synchronous, all works.

I wonder how I can force the cursor to stay WaitCursor.

Comment: You need just `Application.UseWaitCursor = True/False` or `Me.UseWaitCursor = True/False`, to limit the wait cursor to the current Form. `Application.DoEvents()` etc. are not needed. Avoid `Task.Factory.StartNew()` in the implementation of a method. Run a Task instead. Meaning, `Task.Run(LoadData)`, which should become `private function LoadData() as Task`

Comment: `LoadData()` can be `async`.

Comment: Thank you @Jimi . I'm using .NET 4 which  unfortunately doesn't have the `Task.Run` and `async` operations.

Comment: [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) (you need at least VS 2012). Anyway, you have `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, possibly combined with a [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource). If a User can do nothing in the meanwhile, as the WaitCursor implies, you could just make everything synchronous. Btw, since you're using an ancient Framework version, this information should be in the question or in tags.